# OpenGL rotation about z-axis

Tags: opengl, rotation

Rotation about Z-axis 45 degrees : `glRotatef(45.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);`
For rotation about Z-axis 45 degrees about the point (10.0,-5.0,0.0), do I need to translate?

Comment: for rotation around a point, yes, you would also need to translate. It's up to you if you want to translate, rotate your object, then translate back to that doesn't cascade through your next transform, or put those two between glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() calls

Comment: push,gltranslatef,glrotatef,pop. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The thing about the glRotatef() function is that it only can rotate arround the origin. So for a rotation arround a specific point, one needs to translate that point to origin, perform the rotation, and translate back. So, for your point (10, -5, 0) you would do:

```
glPushMatrix(); // you do this to avoid disturbing the transformation matrices for any code following the below lines

glTranslatef(-10, +5, 0); // translate so that (10, -5, 0) lies at the origin
glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1); // now rotate
glTranslatef(10, -5, 0); // translate back

// now you have rotated the scene by 45 degrees arround z-axis, at point (10, -5, 0)

// (draw your object *here*)

glPopMatrix(); // the old matrix is back

// now it is as if nothing happened
```

The push / pop matrix is often misunderstood, that's why i exemplified. In the new OpenGL, there is no implicit matrix stack so one needs to manage his matrices by hand. It gets slightly more complicated, but in return there's no confusion.